# create a custom Linux command for repetitive commands

Tags: linux, shell, grep, zsh

I find myself running this command all the time

```
grep -r "somestring" /workplace/scripts /workplace/server
```

I would like to replace it with a simple custom command

```
s "somestring"
```

which will do the same thing.

how do I do this? I'm new to linux.

Comment: what shell are you using? bash?

Comment: I have zsh installed. can I set this command as alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example suggests that the variable is the search string.  You could define a function:

```
s() {
  grep -r -- "$1" /workplace/scripts /workplace/server
}
```

and invoke it by saying:

```
s "somestring"
```

Comment: where do I define this function? in my .zshrc?

Comment: If you want it to be permanent, then in `.zshrc` else on the shell prompt.

Comment: worked really well. I have a follow up question. Is it possible to enter "somestring" without quotes and then have function s convert it to string?

Comment: @sublime If it's a single word that you are searching for then you don't need to quote it.

Comment: @sublime If it is multiple words, you can use `$*` instead of `$1`: `s () { grep -r "$*" /w/scr /w/srv }`. Then you can invoke it like this `s some longer string` and grep will called with `"some longer string"`. Note: multiple whitespaces (including tab) will be squashed to a single space. So you cannot look for `a    few   more   spaces` with that as it will be convertet to `a few more spaces`.